# Google Analytics Funnel Visualisation (entrance)

Tags: google-analytics, funnelweb

I  am a little stuck with Google analytics using the Funnel Visualisation feature.

Where it says '(entrance)' with a number, when entering a Funnel Visualisation.

what does this represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates the number of people that entered your site on the particular page or set of pages represented by the first step in your funnel.

Comment: Just so I am clear, it is the amount of users that are outside the realms of my site, e.g. google.co.uk. And arriving directly onto the first page in my funnel as the first page visited of my site?

Comment: @carlsoja i am little confused as in mobile app only users can enter 2nd screen of say "join process" through 1st and its showing that most of the users came like this. 
But along with that there is mentioned "entrance" which is directly pointing to the 2nd screen.. what does this means? I am assuming its because user exits the app on 2nd screen and then when came back again to app it came to foreground and it is recored as entrance.?